# Compare numbers in list of prices in a single column in Excel — and spot when numbers are lower instead of higher

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've googled this and found only comparisons of 2 columns but not what I need specifically.  I hope someone can help.

I have a list of 55,000 products in a spreadsheet so this precludes me going over it manually. :)

There are 5 rows for each product, separated by a blank row as shown below.

What I need is to find the place where the 2nd row in each product is lower than the 1st row and  identify it with a color perhaps and then correct and make it 50 more than the 1st row.

ProductName Price

- aaaaaaa 100
- aaaaaaa 150
- aaaaaaa 200
- aaaaaaa 250
- aaaaaaa  50
- blank row
- bbbbbbb 100
- bbbbbbb 150
- bbbbbbb 200
- bbbbbbb 250
- bbbbbbb  50
- blank row
- ccccccc 100
- ccccccc 150
- ccccccc 200
- ccccccc 250
- ccccccc  50

Is there a relatively simple way to do this?  It seems like there should be but I'm not that experienced with Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpreted your request correctly, this will do what you described.

```
Sub ReverseLoop()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow

    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value And Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> "" Then
    Debug.Print Cells(i, 1).Value
    Debug.Print Cells(i, 2).Value
        If Cells(i, 2).Value < Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
            Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: That's almost perfect..  I can modify the price in the same loop that you put in the background color.  However, where is the reference to the column?  In the real case, the column is J.  But I don't see any reference to B in your code?

Comment: Also, this may be because I am unfamiliar with the coding, but where is the definition of the length of each loop/product, i.e., 6—being the number of rows for each item explaining the 1st and 2nd in each loop.

Comment: Cells(i, 1)...means Cells(row,column); the row will increment by 1 each time you iterate through the loop and the column will always be 1, so Column A (this is fixed, in this particular case). The last row is determined by 'lastRow'.  You iterate down through the list.  You can start at the bottom and go up.  You have to move up if you are deleting rows; that's the only way to do it.  In this scenario, it doesn't matter if you are looping down or up, because nothing is being deleted.

Comment: Hit F8 over and over and over to step through the code one line at a time.  You can see how the code works, as you go, line by line.

Comment: I'll do that..  re: the column, I understand the row stuff more or less, I just am not sure how to select column J to begin the looping/checking.  As it is right now, I'm getting a type mismatch cause there aren't numbers where the looping is happening. But I will try to figure out... thanks so much for your help!

Comment: BTW, after your line that sets the color, I added this trying to correct the price : Cells(i, 2).Value =Cells(i, 2).Value + 77 — and that's causing the error 13

Comment: Cells(i, 10) -- Column J is 10; it's the 10th letter in the alphabet.